# apply formula and FillDown on each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply a formula to an entire column (B) in all sheets but just as far down as there is data in column A. I was trying the Filldown formula and am running into:

> Related to Error 1004:

`Range("B1:B" & LastRow).FillDown`

Full Macro:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Range("B1") = "=IF(A1=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),TRUE,FALSE)": Range("B1:B" & LastRow).FillDown
Next sht
```

Comment: Where do you determine `LastRow`? Note - no need for `FillDown`, you can write the formula to the entire range in one line.

Comment: If `LastRow` has no value, then `Range("B1:B")` isn't a valid range expression that Excel can parse, so you get error 1004. If it's declared as a `Long` but wasn't assigned, then you get `Range("B1:B0")` and that isn't a valid range expression either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment stated, `LastRow` is not declared or given a value.

Also the `FillDown` is not needed, and neither is the IF part of the formula:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    sht.Range("B1:B" & LastRow) = "=A1=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)"
Next sht
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks Scott. and thanks for the lesson on the formula!